# Getting a token with Django Oauth Toolkit

Tags: django, oauth-2.0

I have a doubt:

According to the documentation, for getting a token i need to do this:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=<user_name>&password=<password>&scope=read" http://<client_id>:<client_secret>@localhost:8000/o/token
```

In my system, i have two possibilities of login, one with the auth user of django and another one with facebook. The one of the auth user everything is working correctly, but with facebook i stored the credentials of the user in another table, not in auth user. So when i try to have a token i cannot make it because i do not have a username and a password of the `auth` user of `django` that the `oauth` toolkit force me to have it in the `POST`.

How can i make it to have both chances of getting a token, with `username & password` and with useridfacebook and token of facebook?

Thank you for your help.

Greetings.

Answer (score 2):

You can override DOT's default behaviour and authenticate users by writing your own OAuth2Validator class, something like:

```
from oauth2_provider.oauth2_validators import OAuth2Validator

class MyOAuth2Validator(OAuth2Validator):
    def validate_user(self, username, password, client, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Check username and password correspond to a valid and active User, if fails
        try Facebook token authentication
        """
        u = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if u is None or not u.is_active:
           u = authenticate_with_facebook()

        if u is not none and u.is_active:
           request.user = u
           return True

        return False
```

then you have to tell DOT to use your class and not the default one putting something like this in your settings:

```
OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    # other DOT settings
    'OAUTH2_VALIDATOR_CLASS': 'your_app_name.MyOAuth2Validator',
}
```

HTH

Comment: I think that is better to make another authentication backend. I think it´s better because you don`t need to override the library. 'APP.backends.FacebookBackend',
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'.    So first it try to authenticate with facebook backend and then with the normal auth backend. If some one wants the details for how to make that, just ask me. :)

Comment: @RodrigoLópez I am trying to solve almost same issue, can you enlighten me, how you solved it?

Comment: @arnold Hi! Like i commented in the previous comment, the better option i think is to use another backend. In the setting file you declare another backend like this: AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'project.backends.FacebookBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
)  And then you create your file backends.py with the class FacebookBackend, using the method authenticate you make all the logic necessary for the authentication. I hope you understand me, if you don't, tell me and i give you the files example.